# Is there a way either via REST APIs or SDKto change a device’s org in IoT Central?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-central, azure-iot-hub-device-management

When I create a device via the IoT Hub SDK it assigns the device to the parent org.  Is there a way to change the org programmatically via the SDK or the REST (IoT Central or Hub)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `PATCH /api/devices/:id?api-versoin=2022-07-31` with JSON payload:

```
{
   "organizations": ["org-id-to-be-updated"]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "org-id" aspect.  Do you mean the organization name or an actual ID?  I have tried a couple of things and they throw me 400s.  I used the "Org Name" and I also tried the "Parent Org / Child Org Name".

Comment: You can Try GET /api/organizations, find the org id from response payload